# How do I run camel timer after fixed interval, but only in given time range

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wrote a apache timer which runs after every 5min. But now I need to run it only from 8am to 10pm.
How can I do that? I did not find any such in apache camel documentation.

```
<route id="transactionHeath" startupOrder="1">
        <from uri="timer:transactionHeath?delay=1000&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period=300s" />
//logic
</route>
```

Comment: Try Camel scheduledRoutePolicy where you specify the time to run as a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html where you may configure a quartz based policy like this

```
<bean id="startPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz.CronScheduledRoutePolicy">
    <property name="routeStartTime" value="0 0/5 8-22 ? * *"/>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="testRoute" routePolicyRef="startPolicy" autoStartup="false">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="mock:success"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```